# Creating recursive function but getting error when using argument

Tags: f#

I'm trying to make a recursive function in F# and am really new in F# and functional programming so this is probably basic stuff.

```
let rec groupTheResults (htmlNodes : seq<HtmlNode>, resultList: List<HtmlNodeGroup>) :List<HtmlNodeGroup> =
    if Seq.length htmlNodes > 0 then
        let listThing = Seq.take 2 htmlNodes
        []
    else []
```

If I remove `let listThing = Seq.take 2 htmlNodes` then the compiler is all happy. Am I doing something illegal or what?

Comment: What error do you get when you leave the `let` line in?

Comment: For me with some dummy definitions this code compiles fine.

Comment: error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'else' in expression. Expected 'in' or other token.

Comment: And It should work, cant really see what should do the difference... hmm

Comment: Is it possible you are mixing tabs and spaces here in a way that's causing the F# compiler to believe that `[]` is aligned with the `if` instead of with the `let`

Comment: yeah was thinking that also, I had #indent "off" but removed it all and used spaced instad in hope that would fix it, and no tabs anywahere. Didnt help

Comment: You get that error with `#indent "off"` - possibly it is hanging around from somewhere

Comment: Ah yes, closed the interactive F#  window and reloaded all the stuff and it worked, this means its time for bed! thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some discussion in the comments, that error is generated using

```
#indent "off"
```

which disables F#'s whitespace sensitivity.  As a result, an `in` expected after the `let ...` line.

You need to reload your fsi session (rightclick -> reset interactive session) to clear it.  Typing

```
#indent "on"
```

might also work